# jdb not recognizing '--add-reads' option

Tags: java, jdb

I'm working on a project where an invocation of a java file is returning a NullPointerException, but I'm not getting any clues as to why, so I'd like to run it through jdb.   According to to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) page, I should be able to simply replace the call to `java` with `jdb`, but when I do, I'm getting the error:

```
/auto/tools/java/jdk-14.0.1/bin/jdb --add-reads stringtemplate=foostring  -p ./tools/foo:./tools/bar -m foo/com.bar.foo.FOO  -tp ./bar/ -p -o bin/foo -i foo.in

invalid option: --add-reads
```

Is there a trick I'm missing to allow me to pass all these options to jdb?

Answer (score 0):

Java commands (java, javac, jdb) do not use the GNU double-dash convention.  Use a single dash.

Or if that's an option for the program itself, it should probably come after the class name.

Comment: If I run `/auto/tools/java/jdk-14.0.1/bin/jdb -add-reads blah=blah`, it fails, as does `/auto/tools/java/jdk-14.0.1/bin/java -add-reads blah=blah`...   The original java accepts only the double dash, but the jdb does not accept either

Comment: You're right; java now has double-dash options as well. I'd never noticed. Sorry.   But --add-reads is described as being 'specific to the HotSpot virtual machine', so maybe you get something different under the debugger?